# Using distinct for one categorical variable and not unique for other categorical column

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have a dataset which has multiple "Specialty" variable and discharge variable(two values: in hospital and post discharge) for each patient id. I want to count distinct patient id's per specialty irrespective of "unique discharge variable".

```
PatientID   Specialty   admission_date  Discharge
1           Geriatrics  2017-11-08      In_Hospital
1           Nephrology  2017-10-21      Post_discharge
1           Cancer      2017-10-21      Post_discharge
1           Geriatrics  2017-10-21      Post_discharge
```

I want the output to look like

```
Geriatrics  1
Nephrology  1
Cancer      1
```

And want to eliminate the last row of Geriatrics since it is a duplicate value and falls under an earlier date.

I have tried this but it counts Geriatrics in both groups "Inhospital" as well as "post discharge"

```sql
Select DISTINCT [Speciality],[Thirty_day_Mortality_detail],
count(Distinct[PatientID]) as number_of_patients_died
 FROM #data
group by [Speciality],[Thirty_day_Mortality_detail]
 ORDER BY [Speciality]
```

Comment: This one varies based on which DBMS you're using. e.g. MS SQL, Oracle, DB2. Can you please correct the tags.